# Rails 3 and routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get the path even if I don't provide all the options.
E.g. If I pass **:controller => 'users', :action => 'index'** I should get **/users** (It can be performed with Rails.application.routes.url_for), but if I pass smth like this **:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'**, it should return **/users/:id**, the same is with nested routes: **:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'** #=> **/users/:user_id/posts**

Is there any default possibility to emulate this behavior?

Comment: So, if you don't provide a user id, how do you expect to get `/users/:user_id/posts`?

Comment: That is my task =( I somehow have to get such kind of path

Comment: What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: I don't know really =) I know how to do this by traversing all the routes, but i hoped there is a standard rails solution

Comment: "If you don't know where you're going, any road will get you there." (pseudo-quote from Alice in Wonderland)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate an string representation of an incomplete route like "/users/:user_id/posts" Rails has a mechanism for this when you run the rake routes command from the console. I'd recommend looking at [the implementation of that](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake) and using the underlying classes they depend on. ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector looks promising.